# C# AES encryption behaving strangely

Tags: c#, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in C# using this piece of code:

```
public static string AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
     // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
     using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
     aesAlg.Key = Key;
     aesAlg.IV = IV;

     // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform
     ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

     // Create the streams used for encryption
     using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
     using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
     using StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);

     // Write all data to the stream
     swEncrypt.Write(plainText);

     return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msEncrypt.ToArray());
}
```

This is largely based on the sample found here: [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8).

However, the results are somewhat strange and unpredictable - one time I ran the code and got some string as a result, the other time the resulting string (and the `msEncrypt` stream) were empty, and one time the application even froze. I don't understand what the problem is.

**Edit:**
I just ran the code again, on this line:

```
 aesAlg.Key = Key;
```

something strange happened, I got this error:

[image]

Here is how I actually call this method:

```
public static class Authentication
{
        ...

        private static readonly AesEncryption aes = new AesEncryption();

        public static string GenerateToken()
        {
            AuthenticationData data = new AuthenticationData()
            {
                // some data
            };

            string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            return AesEncryption.AesEncrypt(serialized, aes.Key, aes.IV);
        }
}
```

Comment: All the times you were encrypting the same string using the same key? Can you share the sample input string, key and the output you are getting? What is the expected output?

Comment: I think that the using keyword is disposing objects immediately, instead you should use curly brackets

Comment: @Phate01 it is not, it's a new c# 8 syntax, it will be disposed on the scope exit, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: bad syntax for using statement missing brackets '{}'

Comment: @Tohm no, it's valid C# 8 syntax as Renat already explained

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. i see this. I need to update a little bit my knowledge. :)

Comment: @Eutherpy encryption generates random byte sequences. Some of these will be invalid for UTF8. Use [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) instead. This won't freeze the application though. Freezes are caused by infinite loops, hidden exceptions or deadlocked async code

Comment: @Eutherpy post code that actually reproduces the problem - plaintext, key, IV, result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added more details, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

1. The `SteamWriter` isn't closed before the stream is used. There's no call to [StreamWriter.Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?view=netframework-4.8) either. StreamWriter uses a buffer internally and writes it out to the
   stream when it's full.

   The StreamWriter doesn't know it's writing to
   a MemoryStream, all streams look the same to it. Given how small the
   plaintext is in most examples, no flushing will occur before trying
   to read the data from the memory stream.
2. UTF8 supports only a limited set of byte sequences. Good encryption algorithms though generate essentially random sequences. Some of them won't correspond to any valid UTF8 sequence. One of the most common way to encode binary data as text is to use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. That's what most encryption or hashing samples show.

The code should change to something like  :

```
public static string AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
     // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
     using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
     aesAlg.Key = Key;
     aesAlg.IV = IV;

     ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

     using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
     using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
     using StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt);
     swEncrypt.Write(plainText);

     //CHANGES HERE
     swEncrypt.Flush();
     return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
}
```

The sample doesn't suffer from this problem because it uses explicit `using` blocks, so the writer is closed *before* the memory stream is used :

```
using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
        }
        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Neither Visual Studio nor Resharper would suggest using a `using` statement in this case, as the `writer` is clearly closed in the innermost block.

**Don't mix `using` styles**

You can mix using blocks and statements, eg :

```
using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
{
    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
}
encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
```

Given the confusion caused already though, you probably shouldn't. The code isn't that much cleaner and it already caused a problem. Someone else looking at the same code in the future may get confused as well and use a bad refactoring

Comment: @Mr.AF there is, because they *aren't* disposed. Try the code. Without an explicit `Flush` the stream remains empty

Comment: This is what I thought but there is no need of manually flush. Just reduce the last using scope. See my answer for more details.

Comment: That's what reducing the scope does. Flush the writer

Comment: Yep. We agree each other. I am just pointing that you can do the same thing just reducing using spcopes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That helped! I was stupid to just assume that the `using` statement would do exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe some problem with buffers and flushing the streams.

Try to using scope just `swEncript` before `msEncript.ToArray()`

```
  public static string AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
         // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
         using Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
         aesAlg.Key = Key;
         aesAlg.IV = IV;

         // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform
         ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

         // Create the streams used for encryption
         using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
         using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
         using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
             // Write all data to the stream
             swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
         }

         return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msEncrypt.ToArray());

    }
```

Comment: UTF8 can only handle a very limited set of byte sequences

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's will be another question for the OP. I am assuming that UTF encoding it is not the main issue.

Comment: Both issues are pretty bad and result in bad data that can't be decrypted. Both need to be fixed for `AesEncrypt` to work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the key and IV pass in each time you call the AesEncrypt method were different.
For me it's working fine with the example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
        AesEncrypt("Hello World", aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        AesEncrypt("Hello World", aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        AesEncrypt("Hello World", aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        AesEncrypt("Hello World", aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        AesEncrypt("Hello World", aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string AesEncrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(msEncrypt.ToArray()));
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msEncrypt.ToArray());

                }

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: No it's not. Encryption generates random sequences. Only a few of them are valid UTF8 sequences